# country picker swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, pickerview

I would like implement a native iOS country picker in swift 4. 
Currently I have a table which contain the countries code:

```
var countriesCodes = NSLocale.isoCountryCodes as [String]
```

I implement the delegate, and I have a problem in the data source. 
How to convert each country code in country name?

Comment: How do you implement the delegate and what is the problem in your data source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert each country code key into its localised display name using the following function provided in Foundation ([documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293396-localizedstring)):

```
Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode:)
// "NZ" -> "New Zealand"
```

You can convert your country code array to display names using `flatMap`:

```
let countryNames = countriesCodes.flatMap(
    Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode:))
```

Although you may wish to make a tuple pair of the ISO country code and its localised display name together, which would be much more useful:

```
let countryCodesAndNames = countriesCodes.flatMap { code in
    Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: code).map { (code, $0) }
}
// countryCodesAndNames is type [(String, String)]
// which is (ISO code, displayName)
// eg.
print(countryCodesAndNames[0])
// prints ("AC", "Ascension Island")
```